# Harmonized Standard for the safety of refrigerated lab device

Tags: certification, compliance

I am wondering about the harmonized safety standard for the refrigerated lab devices. I have seen two standards EN 61010-2-011 & EN 378-1&2.
But none of these standards are available in the harmonized standards list of Low voltage Directive 2014-35-EU so that it is not possible to mention it in the EC Declaration. In the list there is one standard EN 60335-2-24 but it is for the household appliance.

Can anyone provide the specific standard for the safety of refrigerated lab devices?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about Electrical Engineering.

Comment: Ok then brhans can you suggest me the specific group from which I can get my answer?

Comment: No, I have no idea where you could get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [DIN EN ISO 13732-3:2008-12](https://www.beuth.de/en/standard/din-en-iso-13732-3/111625012) Ergonomics of the thermal environment - Methods for the assessment of human responses to contact with surfaces - Part 3: Cold surfaces

Comment: Thanks for the info G.B.